# what is the designed purpose of serializable interface in java ? why wouldn't kafka mandate every entity to implement serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka

I know this might be quite old question, but I am confused.
So far as I know, with the Reflection API, we can serialize instances, then why does java need an empty interface like Serializable ? I read from an article that this is designed for safety reasons, i.e., only instances marked Serializable can be serialized. if this is so important however, I see in many frameworks, like kafka, the instances don't have to implement Serializable. won't they encounter safety occasions ? what is the difference ?

Comment: Because some things you don't want to serialize, such as passwords.

Comment: Kafka has its own Serializer class. **That is mandated**. Strings, Integers, etc have known byte formats. You shouldn't use Java Serializable types as messages, instead use cross language RPC formats like JSON, AVRO, Protobuf, etc